# JSON containing single quote causes syntaxerror

Tags: javascript, php, json, syntax-error

So I have data that needs to be fetched through php. This data should then be saved to a javascript variable in the .php file echoing the value:

```
$json = json_encode($requirements);
echo "<script>
        var myvar = '<?php echo $json; ?>';
      </script>";
```

The data contains a single quote which gives syntax error in Chrome:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

The page source look something like by the error:

```
var myvar = '<?php echo {"data":{"data":{"1":{"description":"Don'    t}}}}; ?>';
```

where the entire string up until ""Don'" is in red.

What is the right way of keeping json_encode from failing (apart from calling the data directly to js)?

Comment: Did you mean to use it as a string, or for it to be interpreted as an object literal, eg you wouldn't have to call `JSON.parse` later? If the latter don't surround it in quotes at all

Comment: Not surounding it in quotes gives another error about "<" being unexpected. I accepted an answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape `'` chars then, for example by using backslash `\`:

```
{"data":{"data":{"1":{"description":"Don\'t}}}}
```

Or as you are using php you can use [`addslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) function

Comment: Using addslashes worked! Thanks!

At W3 it says "PHP runs addslashes() on all GET, POST, and COOKIE data by default". I'm unsure how this data is recieved other than it is in response to a SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

I have also experienced same problem with Single & Double quote.
You can resolve it easily by changing the single & double quote. Check below example.

```
$array = array(
         "data" => array("data" => array ("desc" => "don't"))
        );

$json = json_encode($array);        

echo "<script>
        var myvar = ".$json.";
        console.log(myvar);
      </script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape double quotes, Try:

```
 var myvar = "<?php echo '{\"data\":{\"data\":{\"1\":{\"description\":\"Don\'t}}}}'; ?>";
 alert(myvar)
```